# Why to use spark core built in transformations/functions when the same job can be done by running sql queries using createOrReplaceTempView?

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I'm new to spark, I found that we can achieve the same result using createOrReplaceTempView for a job that had been done using spark core built in transformations.
So anyone who knows sql can work using the sql in spark session without learning spark core transformations, so why to learn spark core built in transformations/functions?

Example:

```
emp = spark.read.option("header",true).csv("/Users/admin/employeeData.csv")
emp.createOrReplaceTempView("employee")

// Using sql 
spark.sql("select * from employee).show()

// Using spark core 
emp.filter("name"=='John').show()
```

I found a somewhat related query here ([why use spark core API (RDD) when you can do most of it in spark-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966657/why-use-spark-core-api-rdd-when-you-can-do-most-of-it-in-spark-sql)) as its quite old so does it have the right explanation/answer or can anyone explain it better?

Comment: the answer still fits